# How to obtain audio chunks for analysis in core audio or AVFoundation

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, core-audio

I need to analyse chunks of audio data of (approximately) 1 second with a sample rate of 8kHz. Although the audio will be recorded in real time, it will only be used for detecting specific events. Hence, there are no strict latency requirements. What would be the best framework to use in this case?

I already started learning Core Audio and I worked through the book Learning Core Audio. With the minimal amount of Swift documentation available on the internet I was able to set up an AUGraph for iOS to record audio with the remote I/O audio unit and to get acces to the raw samples with the output render callback. Unfortunately, I got stuck to create chunks of 1 seconds of audio samples to perform the audio analysis. Could a custom AudioBufferList be used for this? Or could a large ringbuffer be implemented on the remote I/O audio unit (like it is required in case of a HAL audio unit)?

I also tried to adopt AVFoundation with AVAssetReader to obtain the audio chunks. Although I was able to obtain samples of a recorded audio signal, I did not succes in creating a buffer of 1 second (and I even don’t know whether it would be possible to do this in realtime). Would AVFoundation be a good choice in this situation anyhow?

I would appreciate any advice on this.

A main problem for me is the fact that I try to use Swift but that there is not much example code available and that there is even less documentation. I feel that it would be better to switch to Objective-C for audio programming, and to stop trying to get everything in Swift. I am curious whether this would be a better time investment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Audio is a C API.
Objective-C is an extension of C.   I find that Objective-C is much nicer for working with core audio than swift.

I created a cross platform c lockless ring buffer.  There is sample code that demonstrates setting up the ring, setting up the mic, playing audio, and reading and writing from the ring.

The ring records that last N number of seconds that you specify.  Old data is overwritten by new data.  So you specify that you want the latest 3 seconds recorded.     The sample I show plays a sine wave while recording through the microphone.  Every 7 seconds, it grabs the last 2 seconds of recorded audio.

[Here is the complete sample code on github](https://github.com/jayberss/CrossPlatformAudioRingBuffer).

Comment: This is very helpful! Thanks a lot. Based on your comment and my experience with Core Audio in Swift, I just decided to switch to objective-C. Although I worked through “Learning Core Audio”, I probably need to increase my objective-C skills much more, but I will definitely try to understand your code in more detail. For now I was wondering whether there is a major difference between the ringbuffer you implemented, and the CARingBuffer from Apple and the TPCircularBuffer by Michael Tyson?

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at TP.  But generally anything written by M. Tyson is good.   I haven't looked at CA but I'm sure it's solid.

Most ring buffers allow you to "consume" and remove the earliest data in the buffer (FIFO).   So reads from the ring get the oldest data. Mine works on the newest data.  It gets data between say 2 seconds ago and now.    Assume you have a buffer of 6 seconds.  My reads get the seconds 4 through 6 where other ring buffer implementation get seconds 0 through 2.  So mine is like a LIFO.   
If you don't have any realtime constraints, TP or CA may work OK.

Comment: I finally worked through your code and I understand it fairly well. However, when running the code, the play through does not work (just the sine wave). I observed that there is no AudioUnitRender in the render callback (outRenderProc) to draw from the system input (just the sine wave generator). But when I add the AudioUnitRender nothing change. Might it be that the interruptionListener is not configured correctly? I tried to modify it, but could not get it working. I hope that you could comment on this.

Comment: Are you trying to get audio from the mic?  If not where is the the source of your audio and is the speaker playing anything?

Comment: I found that the issue appears to be related to the stereo stream format on the input scope of the i/o AU. When I set a AudioUnitRender instead of the sine wave in the render callback, no audio is played (although it works for mono stream format). My problem is to copy the input samples to the output channels so that it can be played in stereo. I placed a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35015519/how-to-render-system-input-from-the-remote-i-o-audio-unit-and-to-play-these-samp). Possibly, you could help me out here too, but your code helped me a lot to understand the material!

Answer (score 3):

For analyzing 1 second windows of audio samples, the simplest solution would be to use the Audio Queue API with a lock-free ring buffer (say around 2 seconds long) to record samples.  You can use a repeating nstimer task to poll how full the buffer is, and emit 1 second chunks to a processing task when they become available.

Core Audio and the RemoteIO Audio Unit is for if you need much shorter data windows with latency requirements on the order a few milliseconds.

Comment: This is clear. Because I potentially want to do real-time audio processing in the future, I think Audio Units would be best for me. Although your answer is useful, I accepted the other answer because of the example code (unfortunately, I cannot accept both).